# after updating my classes and the way I create my sprites the function that has the move around no longer works

Tags: python, pygame

after I had set up my subclasses the function I use to have  them interact with other things no longer works, I am wondering on the best way to fix this either  by setting up a list to store their positions or some other way though I am not sure on how to go about this.
one of the classes:

```
 class Prey(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
        def __init__(Self):
            super().__init__()
            Self.preyImg=pygame.image.load('Prey.png')
            Self.preyX=300
            Self.preyY=700
            Self.screen= screen
            
             
        def Render(Self,Img,X,Y):
            Self.screen.blit(Img,(X,Y))
            
        def delete(Self):
            i.delete()
```

and here's the function:

```
def Track(AgressorX,DefenderX,AgressorY,DefenderY):
global XMovement#make variables global so it actually works
global YMovement

if AgressorX > DefenderX:#finds whether its position then moves left/righ,up/down depending on its location
    XMovement=-0.25

elif AgressorX< DefenderX:
    XMovement=0.25
    
else:
    XMovement=0
    

if AgressorY > DefenderY:
    YMovement=-0.25
    
elif AgressorY < DefenderY: 
    YMovement=0.25
    
else:
    YMovement=0
```

I think it may be due to how I'm setting the the render up though I am not completely sure

full code:

```
  #program to simulate wild life
#imports
import math
import random
import pygame,sys 
import random
import pdb
from pygame.locals  import *


timmer=1




class Animal(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(Self,):
        super().__init__()
        Self.Image=pygame.image.load('Blank.png').convert_alpha()
        Self.rect=Self.Image.get_rect()
        Self.Xpos=0
        Self.Xpos=0
        Self.Screen= screen
        #Self.Width=Width
        #Self.Height=Height
        #Self.Energy=0
        
        

    def BoundryX(entityX):
        if entityX<=0:
            entityX=0
        elif entityX>=600:
            entityX=600
            
    def BoundryY(entityY):
        if entityY<=0:
            entityY=0
        elif entityY>=800:
            entityY=800
            
   
        


        
class Predator(Animal):
    def __init__(Self):
        super().__init__()
        Self.Img=pygame.image.load('Icon.png')
        Self.PredatorX=0
        Self.PredatorY=0
        Self.screen= screen
        
        
    def Render(Self,Img,X,Y):
        Self.screen.blit(Img,(X,Y))
        
        



         
class Prey(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(Self):
        super().__init__()
        Self.preyImg=pygame.image.load('Prey.png')
        Self.preyX=300
        Self.preyY=700
        Self.screen= screen
        
         
    def Render(Self,Img,X,Y):
        Self.screen.blit(Img,(X,Y))
        
    def delete(Self):
        i.delete()



    
CarrotImg=pygame.image.load('carrot.png')
CarrotX=100
CarrotY=300
foodamount=7


def food():
    #CarrotX=random.randint(10,950)
    #CarrotY=random.randint(10,750)
    screen.blit(CarrotImg,(CarrotX,CarrotY))
    
    

#setup pygame
pygame.init()

#caption and Icons
pygame.display.set_caption("Game Of Life")

#predator icon

predatorImg=pygame.image.load('Icon.png')
predatorX=900
predatorY=100
predatorX_change=0


#Prey Icon
preyImg=pygame.image.load('Prey.png')
preyX=300
preyY=700
PreyX_change=0


        
#def delete():
        #prey.delete()
        
preyImg=pygame.image.load('Prey.png')
preyX=300
preyY=700
PreyX_change=0

#def Prey():
    #screen.blit(preyImg,(preyX,preyY))


#Finding closest prey
def FindClosestItem(AgressorX,DefenderX,AgressorY,DefenderY):
    dist = math.sqrt((AgressorX-DefenderX)**2 + (AgressorY-DefenderY)**2)#finds distance in pixels
    

#create pop out for game
screen=pygame.display.set_mode((1000,800))





def Track(AgressorX,DefenderX,AgressorY,DefenderY):
    global XMovement#make variables global so it actually works
    global YMovement
    
    if AgressorX > DefenderX:#finds whether its position then moves left/righ,up/down depending on its location
        XMovement=-0.25
    
    elif AgressorX< DefenderX:
        XMovement=0.25
        
    else:
        XMovement=0
        
    
    if AgressorY > DefenderY:
        YMovement=-0.25
        
    elif AgressorY < DefenderY: 
        YMovement=0.25
        
    else:
        YMovement=0
        
        
def EatPrey(predatorX,PreyX,predatorY,preyY):
    dist = math.sqrt((predatorX-preyX)**2 + (predatorY-preyY)**2)
    if dist < 20:
        return True
    else:
        return False


#setup test

predator=Predator()
prey=Prey()

#Sprite groups
all_sprites_Wolves=pygame.sprite.Group()


all_sprites_Rabbits=pygame.sprite.Group()


all_sprites_Carrots=pygame.sprite.Group()

    

#game loop
running=True
while running:

    #Back ground colour
    screen.fill((0,128,0))
    
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type==pygame.QUIT:
            running=False
    


    
   
    
    predator.Render(pygame.image.load('Icon.png'),600,700)
    prey.Render(pygame.image.load('Prey.png'),300,700)

    ClosestPrey=FindClosestItem(predatorX,preyX,predatorY,preyY)
    
    
    food()
    
    Track(predatorX,preyX,predatorY,preyY)
    predatorX+=XMovement
    predatorY+=YMovement
    #predatorX=BoundryX(predatorX)
    #predatorY=BoundryY(predatorY)
   
    
    Track(preyX,CarrotX,preyY,CarrotY)
    preyX+=XMovement
    preyY+=YMovement
    #preyX=BoundryX(preyX)
    #preyY=BoundryY(preyY)
    

    #Eat=EatPrey(preyX,preyY,predatorX,predatorY)
    
    #if Eat==True:
        #delete()
        #T=1
    
    #Boundry(prey)
    if preyX<=0:
        preyX=0
    elif preyX>=950:
        preyX=950
    if preyY<=0:
        preyY=0
    elif preyY>=750:
        preyY=750
        #preyY-=1

    #Boundry(predator)
    if predatorX<=0:
        predatorX=0
    elif predatorX>=950:
        predatorX=950
    elif predatorY<=0:
        predatorY=0
    elif predatorY>=750:
        predatorY=750


        
    pygame.display.update()
    
    timmer=timmer+1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your *Sprites* are rendered at constant positions:

> ```py
> predator.Render(pygame.image.load('Icon.png'),600,700)
> prey.Render(pygame.image.load('Prey.png'),300,700)
> ```

You must render the *Sprrites* at the positions (*predatorX*, *predatorY*) respectively (*preyX*, *preyY*):

```py
predator.Render(predatorImg, predatorX, predatorY)
prey.Render(preyImg, preyX, preyY)
```

---

However you don't need the variables at all. Use the instance attributes of the class:

```py
class Prey(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.img = pygame.image.load('Prey.png')
        self.x = 300
        self.y = 700
        self.screen = screen
             
    def Render(self):
        self.screen.blit(self.img, (self.x, self.y))
```

```py
prey = Prey()

# [...]

running = True
while running:
    # [...]

    prey.Render()

    # [...]

    Track(prey.x, CarrotX, prey.y, CarrotY)
    prey.x += XMovement 
    prey.y += YMovement
```

---

Minimal example:

```py
import math
import random
import pygame,sys 
import random
import pdb
from pygame.locals  import *

class Animal(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, image, x, y):
        super().__init__()
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.image = image
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center = (x, y))
    def move(self, mx, my):
        self.x += mx
        self.y += my
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center = (self.x, self.y))
        
class Predator(Animal):
    def __init__(self):
        image = pygame.image.load('Icon.png')
        super().__init__(image, 600, 700)
         
class Prey(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.x = 300
        self.y = 700
        self.image = pygame.image.load('Prey.png')
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center = (self.x, self.y))
    def move(self, mx, my):
        self.x += mx
        self.y += my
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center = (self.x, self.y))

class Carrot(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.x = 100
        self.y = 700
        self.image = pygame.image.load('carrot.png')
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center = (self.x, self.y))
    def move(self, mx, my):
        self.x += mx
        self.y += my
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center = (self.x, self.y))

def Track(AgressorX,DefenderX,AgressorY,DefenderY):
    if AgressorX > DefenderX:
        XMovement=-0.25 
    elif AgressorX< DefenderX:
        XMovement=0.25
    else:
        XMovement=0
        
    if AgressorY > DefenderY:
        YMovement=-0.25
    elif AgressorY < DefenderY: 
        YMovement=0.25
    else:
        YMovement=0
    return XMovement, YMovement

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1000,800))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

timmer = 1
predator = Predator()
prey = Prey()
carrot = Carrot()

all_sprites = pygame.sprite.Group()
all_sprites.add(predator)
all_sprites.add(prey)
all_sprites.add(carrot)

running=True
while running:
    clock.tick(60)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type==pygame.QUIT:
            running=False

    mx, my = Track(predator.x, prey.x, predator.y, prey.y)
    predator.move(mx, my)

    mx, my = Track(prey.x, carrot.x, prey.y, carrot.y)
    prey.move(mx, my)

    screen.fill((0,128,0))
    all_sprites.draw(screen)
    pygame.display.update()
    timmer=timmer+1

pygame.quit()
exit()
```

Comment: (sorry if this what you told me not to do in you earlier post) would storing these values in a list or other format be a better way when attempting to have multiple sprites/ entitles

Comment: ah i see I am sorry

Comment: issue: the image for the "prey" class doesn't move but its X and Y co-ordinates do, is this  because the image has been set to a specific position? or a flaw some where else

Comment: the image for the sprite doesn't move position but the X/Y position for the sprite do

Comment: sorry if you have already seen it but your solution causes the image for the sprite to not move/ be at the correct X and Y co-ordinates

Comment: sorry Ill try and fix it